# Cronjob php script not working

Tags: php, linux, debian

I'm trying to set a cronjob to run every 20 minutes.
This works manually:

```
php /srv/www/mysite.co.uk/public_html/PP/Make_XML.php LONDON
```

I tried to use "crontab -e" and set it even to every 20 minutes with:

```
 */20 * * * * php /srv/www/mysite.co.uk/public_html/PP/Make_XML.php LONDON
```

it was saved to /tmp/crontab.0xYhei9m/crontab

And it doesn't seem to work.
What's wrong here?

EDIT:

Current stats:

*. cron is up and running:

> ```
> root     31855     1  0 08:39 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron
> ```

*. Running "crontab -l" shows:

> */20 * * * * /usr/bin/php /srv/www/mysite.co.uk/public_html/PP/Make_XML.php
>   LONDON

And still no go. Again manually running the script works just fine.

Comment: Maybe the missing details from your question are the key for the answer. At first it's very interesting where's your crontab getting saved.

Comment: What missing details? i use Debian 6

Comment: Is the crontab running as the same user as when running the command manually?

Comment: Don't know too much about crontab but that `/` is very interesting in your entry. Just checked my crontab and mine doesn't contain `/` at all.

Comment: @Treffynnon yes it also said "root has no crontab installing crontab"

Comment: @fabrik thats how you get it to run every 20 mins as opposed to 20 mins past the hour.

Comment: My 30 minute entry start like this: `30 * * * *`

Comment: @fabrik M H DOM MON DOW COMMAND

Comment: @fabrik see http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5 your entry is to run at 30 minutes past the hour and not every thirty minutes.

Comment: @Tom try to make your crontab really simple. So make it `touch()` a new file in `/tmp` and see if that works. Then you can work from there and add the more complex functionality.

Comment: @Treffynnon oops, sry :D

Answer (score 5):

is the cron daemon even running?

Comment: Comment vs Answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83178/answer-vs-comment

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. This would be better as a comment on the question.

Comment: the cron unde usr/sbin/cron is running

Answer (score 1):

> it was saved to /tmp/crontab.0xYhei9m/crontab

Yes - that's the file you just edited - its NOT the file crond reads to fire jobs. Crontab whould then read this file, install the updated crontab in the location where crond looks for it and notify crond it needs to process the file.

Have you checked:

1. crond is running?
2. your uid is allowed to schedule cron jobs (usually via /etc/cron.allow / /etc/cron.deny)
3. that the script really isn't being started by cron and failing due to a permissions error?
4. that the version of crond you are using support $PATH and can find the executable?

Comment: 1. cron (Debian) is running 2.No cron.allow & cron.deny exist 3.Don't know how to check that really 4. I made it /usr/etc/php instead so shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

In case this is already online, try using wget instead of php, with the url instead of the path, ie.:

*/20 * * * * wget http://YOUR_IP/~YOUR_USER/PATH/Make_XML.php

or

*/20 * * * * wget http://mysite.co.uk/PP/Make_XML.php

First make sure the url works , just by opening it with a browser

Hope it helps!

Comment: Have you tried this? Some time ago I had a similar problem and solved it this way. If the cronjobs are working then it wouldn't hurt to give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

Crontab doesn't know anything about `PATH` variable. So use absolute path to your php (/usr/bin/php for e.g.)/ You can run command `which php` to find your php path

Comment: No - most version of crond DO use $PATH (crontab is just a datafile used by crond / a program for accessing / changing the crontab file) - but we don't know what was in the PATH variable when crond was started. Certainly its good practice to use an explicit path to an executable in the crontab